# Find who is holding cryptsetup/LUKS encrypted home (some KDE/X vs common sense madness)

Tags: bash, lsof, luks

I'm fighting some ridiculous no-so-eeasy to debug case with my cryptsetup/LUKS encrypted home directory.

The setup: I have partition that is dedicated to my user home directory and encrypted with cryptsetup/LUKSv2 (lets call this user "crypted"). The directory is automatically mounted on user logon with pam_mount module and unmounted as soon as last session of this user is closed. This seems to work pretty well even for KDE/Plasma session that is started by SDDM.

Unless another user (lets call it "plane") login into KDE/Plasma session while user with crypted (and mounted) home is still active. If so, pam_mount will fail to unmount crypted home on "crypted" user logout giving me:

```
(mount.c:72): Device sdaX_dmc is still in use
(mount.c:72): ehd_unload: Device or resource busy
(mount.c:887): unmount of /dev/sdaX failed
```

`cryptsetup close sdaX_dmc` will give same error preventing me from freeing the device.

This will last until "plane" user will logout and close KDE/Plasma session. Only then I will be able to close crypted device and login with "crypted" user again.

So, ok, not a problem, I thought and did a try to find who is guilty using lsof while "plane" user is still logged in and "crypted" user attempted logout with unmount failed, but:

```
lsof | grep '/home/<mountpoint>'
lsof | grep 'sdaX_dmc'
```

gave me exactly nothing. No process is accessing this directory.

Then I did a try with:

```
ofl /home/<mountpoint>
```

with no success.

SDDM itself is not a problem as I'm able to unmount "crypted" user home while SDDM active and after SDDM restart.

Any ideas how to find the process who is accessing/holding some third-party user home directory? Looks like some KDE/Waylan/X11 is in respond.

Comment: I admittedly have no experience with this scenario.  However, is the "plane" user accessing the already mounted/decrypted partition (i.e. same condition as attempting to unmount busy regular device) ... or .. is plane accessing that via its own  mount/decryption of that home directory ?  In other words, can two users each mount/decrypt their own image of that same device?

Comment: The only other approach I can suggest is to identify all processes accessing the device and killing those before ending your session. The logic for that could be incorporated into a **.bashrc_logout** .

Comment: @EricMarceau to apply some logic on logout I need to find the process responsible for the lock, the rest is not a problem, actually.

Comment: I don't know how, myself, but what you need is **a trace of all processes startup up from boot until your ssh session is opened** (without startx, only console). One of the experts out there must know how to capture and review/analyze that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that firejail is responsible for this.
More info can be found [here](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/5640).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
lsof +D '/home/<mountpoint>'
```

I get a report that looks like this (*giving process and user*):

```
root@OasisMega1:~# lsof +D .
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
Xorg      1793 root  mem    REG    8,3  1310728 12320774 ./.cache/mesa_shader_cache/index
mate-term 2918 root  cwd    DIR    8,3     4096 12320769 .
mate-term 2918 root  mem    REG    8,3    10974 12323714 ./.config/dconf/user
mate-term 2918 root  mem    REG    8,3        2 12321632 ./.cache/dconf/user
bash      8829 root  cwd    DIR    8,3     4096 12320769 .
lsof      8851 root  cwd    DIR    8,3     4096 12320769 .
lsof      8852 root  cwd    DIR    8,3     4096 12320769 .
root@OasisMega1:~#
```

Maybe something you aren't expecting is keeping the device busy.

Similarly, examining the device directly:

```
lsof `df . | grep '/dev/' | awk '{ print $1 }' `
```

Comment: Well, `lsof +D` gave exactly nothing, while second approach with additional `| grep -v 'home/plane_user_home'` revealed two process none of were responsible for blocking "crypted"s home. Still mystery.

Comment: What I actually found is that after logging out from the last "crypted" session and while unmount and cryptsetup reporting that home is "still in use" there are no available crypted files in there. More overt, I can see `.empty` dummy file. May be a bug of cryptsetup.